# Call AlarmManager when phone turned on after new day

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an AlarmManager that I call at the end of every day, ie 23.59PM, to do some stuff for the new day. (Its called, NewDayReceiver.class.) It repeats every day.

I also set a broadcast receiver that will run the alarm on reboot. It all works fine.

However, if the phone is off at the end of the day, the alarm for that day is not called. When the phone is turned back on, on boot the alarm is set again, however its set for the end of the new day. It comes out, that the alarm for that day was never called. For example, if its off Sunday night, on Monday morning the phone is turned on but the alarm hasn't been called. It will only be called Monday night?

How can I do it, that on the boot broadcast receiver, I can check if the alarm was called for that day, and if it wasn't set the alarm to go off right away.

I hope its clear.

Here is my alarm for every day.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewDayReceiver.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

if(!calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
    // Repeat every 24 hours
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "New day alarm set for:" + calendar.getTime() + " and will repeat every day");
}
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver, that I call on boot:

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "999.BootBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent intent) {    
        newDayAlarm(pContext);
        newWeekAlarm(pContext);
    }

    private void newWeekAlarm(Context context) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewWeekReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 55, intent, 0);

        // real for end of week    
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        if(!calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                Log.d(TAG, "New week alarm set for:" + calendar.getTime());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: well you can use SharedPreferences, like. if AlarmManager called path the day's date and true value to SharedPreferences, for more efficient use SQLite database

Comment: So if the phone was off Sunday, when back on on Monday, you want to do things for both Sunday and Monday?

Comment: The method is called at the beginning of the current day. So if the phone was off on Sunday and went back on Monday, it only needs to happen once, on Monday (the new day). Thanks